# Why are enums with negative values causing problems in Objective-C/C?

Tags: objective-c, c, enums, llvm, signed

For various implementation reasons, I've defined the following enum:

```
typedef enum HBSnakeMovementDirection
{
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionUp = 1,
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionDown = -1,
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight = 2,
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionLeft = -2
}
HBSnakeMovementDirection;
```

However, if I try to use `HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight`, I get the following warning:

> `Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'HBSnakeMovementDirection'`

It has no problem with any of the other enum values. What's the problem here? I thought it might have to do with mixing negative and positive enum values, but I can't find out anything definitive about this.

(I was able to come up with all positive enum values that allow me to work around this issue, but it still stumped me, so I thought I'd ask about it.)

I should state that, as with all my projects, I enable almost every warning—hence, `-Wconversion`'s complaints—and treat them as errors. (I like to be as strict as possible at compile time.) I'm using LLVM 1.6.

**UPDATE 1**: Literally any use of `HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight` results in the preceding warning:

```
HBSnakeMovementDirection movementDirectionRight = HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight;
```

I have to cast `HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight` to `HBSnakeMovementDirection` to silence the warning.

**UPDATE 2**: As requested, here is the entire build command that's being issued on my machine:

http://pastie.org/1580957

**UPDATE 3**: Here is the exact project I'm working on hosted on GitHub:

https://github.com/LucasTizma/Hebi

Specifically, the following tree:

https://github.com/LucasTizma/Hebi/tree/89262e2e53881584daf029e3dd5f1e99dfbd6f96

Comment: `int` by default to be `signed` or `unsigned` is compiler specific. So, try using the receiving parameter as `signed int` and check. BTW, show a piece of code of how you are actually using. Why declaration and synonym bearing the same name in your `typedef`. Though this is not the problem, just curious to know.

Comment: @Mahesh, `int` is always `signed` by default.  You might be thinking of `char`, which does have implementation-defined signedness.  @LucasTizma, you need to show us the line and related variable declarations for the place you're using the enumeration value for us to help you.

Comment: §6.7.2.2/2 and /4 in C99 says that enumeration
constant(`HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight`) has a value representable as an `int`,
and enumerated type(`HBSnakeMovementDirection`) shall be capable of
representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.
So, there seems to be no problem in your `enum` type...

Comment: Try to isolate the minimal amount of code that reproduces your problem. `HBSnakeMovementDirection movementDirectionRight =                           HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight; printf("%d\n", movementDirectionRight);` compiles and runs with no warning whatsoever with clang 1.6 and GCC 4.2.1.

Comment: @Mahesh: That's how Apple defines their `enum`s, so that's what I did. @Carl Norum: Literally any use of that particular enumeration constant triggers the warning, but I've included a line of code in my answer as an example.

Comment: Would there be by any chance some old, forgotten `HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight` identifier besides the one in your `enum`? Maybe a `#define` or a `const int`.

Comment: @Bavarious: As I stated, I'm using LLVM 1.6 (with Clang), not GCC. Compiling with LLVM GCC or just GCC seems to work just fine, so I'm wondering if this is an issue with Clang? No, there's no other definition of `HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight`.

Comment: @LucasTizma I listed GCC 4.2.1 because it has the same behaviour as Clang (which implies LLVM) 1.6 in my test case: no warning whatsoever. I’ve built with `-Wall -Wconversion -Wextra`, just to be sure. =)

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the exact clang command-line invocation that’s being used to compile your file?

Comment: @Bavarious: Strange. Feel free to pull down my exact project from GitHub: https://github.com/LucasTizma/Hebi/ Are you able to build that with no issues?

Comment: @Bavarious: I've included the build command in my answer.

Comment: @LucasTizma I’ve found a fix but no explanation yet for it. Might be a bug. Hang on. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Darren said, it does look like a compiler bug, and Dave said it doesn’t happen with Clang 2.0.

I’ve found that the following type definition makes the OP code compile with Clang 1.6:

```
typedef enum HBSnakeMovementDirection 
{
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionUp = 1,     // Default movement direction upon initialization via -init
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionDown = -1,
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionLeft = -2,
    HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight = 2,
    NBSnakeMovementDirectionNone = -3
}
HBSnakeMovementDirection;
```

(note the additional `NBSnakeMovementDirectionNone`)

This could be related to LLVM bug [1884](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1884), which has been fixed.

Comment: Well, I feel better knowing it wasn't related to stupidity on my part. :) I plan on switching over to LLVM 2.0 eventually and—as I point out in the question—I was able to adjust my implementation logic to work with non-negative enumeration constants. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this.  It certainly looks like a compiler bug to me.  The presence of negative values in the enum causes the compiler to mistakenly think that the value of "2" is outside of the range of the enum, hence the warning.

The behavior is the same whether you specify "2" or "HBSnakeMovementDirectionRight":  It accepts 1 and rejects 2.

Edit: I tested this in an existing iPhone project, setting the compiler LLVM 1.6 and setting the `-Wconversion` flag.

```
typedef enum HBSnakeMovementDirection
{
    neg1 = -1,
    pos1 = 1,
    pos2 = 2,
} HBSnakeMovementDirection;

HBSnakeMovementDirection d = -3;  // Warning: Can't convert int to HBSnakeMovementDirection
HBSnakeMovementDirection d = -2;  // OK
HBSnakeMovementDirection d = -1;  // OK
HBSnakeMovementDirection d = 0;  // OK
HBSnakeMovementDirection d = 1;  // OK
HBSnakeMovementDirection d = 2;  // Warning: Can't convert int to HBSnakeMovementDirection
HBSnakeMovementDirection d = pos2;  // Warning: Can't convert int to HBSnakeMovementDirection
```

Comment: Can you post the code?  I've been trying to repro this (unsuccessfully) for about 15 minutes.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: Check out UPDATE 3 in my question. I posted my exact project on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely looks like a compiler bug.  I opened the project in Xcode 3 and compiled, and got the error.  When I opened the project in Xcode 4 and used the clang2.0 compiler, I got no warnings.